# How do I configure a tinymce editor to only upload images to the server only on form submit?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am creating a forum that utilizes the tinymce wysiwyg editor. It seems like the editor's default behavior is to upload an image to the server immediately when a user adds an image to the editor.

What if the user does not want that image anymore? What if a user maliciously adds many, many photos to the server?

I am wanting to submit images to the server only when a user submits a post. That way, I can limit the amount of images downloaded to the server and can better validate the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the configuration setting `automatic_uploads: false`.

With that setting, as long as either `images_upload_url` or `images_upload_handler` are specified, images shouldn't be uploaded automatically and should only be uploaded when `editor.uploadImages()` is called upon form submission.

Here's some more information about `automatic_uploads:`

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#automatic_uploads

*NOTE: Tiny has identified a bug where the `automatic_uploads` setting isn't always respected when uploading via the image dialog. The bug has been logged, and work to fix the bug is currently being scheduled as of this posting. I will edit this post the fix has been released.*

Comment: Thanks. Although, I am wanting to be able to validate how many images users are submitting and such. I wonder if there is a way to submit the images with all the other user input at once. That way, I can validate all the user input and send back an error if validation fails.

Comment: You can call editor.uploadImages() whenever you like. Calling it within your form submission logic would give you the opportunity to perform the sort of validation you are looking for.